# How to apply tps rate on existing resource in aws api gateway using typescript

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I want to apply tps rate on existing resource in api gateway, I'm trying to import or get info about existing api resource from api gateway but not able to import it in proper way. I have tried to get it from the web.

Comment: Seems like you asked the question twice